# What are some use cases for the singlar ray output?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor, shaders

Using the singular ray output, it's possible to detect whether or not the object is being viewed through a perfectly sharp reflection or refraction:

[image]

Besides changing colors of reflections, what are some possible use-cases for this variable?

Comment: Maybe for some sort of vampire effect ? ![vampire suzanne](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jY7Ip.jpg)

Comment: It can be useful for subtle effect in glass refraction without have to go through the pain of caustics effect etc.

Answer (score 1):

I still have not spent the time to do a proper write up of this, but here is a preview of the effect, and the Blend File for your own use.

Even though this seemingly begins to look like a distance based thing, I really believe (in my own opinion, without further study) that this is still using amount of refraction as the basis for this effect, and the margin is pretty small. I would imagine that playing with settings such as the ones found here: [This Link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48226/making-a-realistic-infinite-mirror-tunnel) would change this potential up quite a bit, how ever I can see some sequential lighting animation being done with this node, as long as each light would have to pass through something that would cause this type of refraction like the glass prism shown in this answer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note tat the *Is Singular Ray* value is actually doing nothing in your example.  The trig functions [only take one input](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45094/5705), the second one is ignored.

Comment: Definitely my mistake, I just left the Is Singular Ray Plugged into the math node, and somehow switched and forgot it switched. Great Catch.  I am still experimenting though, and after I do, I'll post a write-up as a Pre-pend to my bogus answer. Just a note on what I'm going to write up... Is Singular Ray can act as an inverse of the Ray Length Node, which may spark some more ideas on how it can be used, but in the write up, I will demonstrate what I mean. Just need to find the time to gather it all together.