# Blender Math Nodes: which input is which (numerator vs denominator)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, mathematics

Is there documentation associated with the cycles nodes, in particular the math nodes? The current documentation in the manual seems to only indicate that there are two values, but not which is which. That's fine for functions that are communicative, but some (like matrix multiply and divide and power) are not.

For example:

[image: divide example]

is this $\frac{1}{input}$ or $\frac{input}{1}$? The same question for a power function, is this:

[image]

$input^\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{2}^{input}$?

Sorry for the beginner questions and I admit I didn't look through the manual in depth, but the section on nodes didn't indicate this. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your questions? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45089/how-are-the-math-node-operations-in-cycles-calculated?rq=1