# How to compare values properly with expression in Animation Nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

Such simple task goes wrong somehow (result of comparing inside `Expression` is far from expected):

[image]

**What did I overlook here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats in general have a limited precision and most real numbers can not be fully represented using a float. So when you set the input float node to `0.1`, it is actually represented internally as `0.100000001490116119384765625`. See this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45089/how-are-the-math-node-operations-in-cycles-calculated/45150#45150) for more information. Python's representation of `0.1` is different from blender's representation, python's is more accurate `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`. Hence the result you see in your setup.

In general, don't try to compare floats as this may yield some unexpected results. You can use something like `isclose()` function to compare floats, this function is the standard math module.

Comment: Well, a man can easily end up in asulym trying to assume that not every 0.1 is equal to 0.1. Thank you, Omar!