# Making a realistic infinite mirror tunnel

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, light

You know when you're standing between two walls that both have mirrors on them and it makes it look like each mirror is an infinite tunnel going into oblivion?

Something like this:

[image]

(photo from [Daniel Hong's website](http://www.egamiobscura.com/new-page/)).

So, I'm trying to achieve the same effect in a claustrophobic elevator scene, using planes with a glossy material, and it looks like the reflections somehow stop or become very dark after a few bounces:

[image]

How could I make the light fade little by little after each bounce and not really ever become completely black?

Comment: In addition to the answer Photon posted, if you want to make the reflection curl up like it does in the reference photo, displacing the geometry or texture slightly should do the trick. Also, the effect of each iteration getting darker is a result of less light being reflected with each bounce (some light is diffused in other directions). Making your Glossy color slightly darker than pure white should give you this (more realistic) effect. I suppose the "completely black" you don't want is where the bounce limit is. Better to veer off at a curve and gradually get darker than to stop abruptly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To make more bounces:

Go to render panel and in Light paths section increase Bounces on Min, Max and Glossy

[image]

To get rid of Darkness:

Go to materials and change both mirrors color to pure white:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your Properties View in the Render Tab search the Light Paths Panel and crank up your Transparency Bounces:

[image: Light Paths Panel]