# Alpha Transparency not working for mesh in Cycles Render

Tags: transparency

I created a text object and then converted it to Mesh (Alt+C).

**What I want to do?** Achieve a fade-in animation. Insert one keyframe for transparency when it is fully transparent, and another when the object's opaque.

**What's the problem?**

I am stuck at the first step. I can't seem to make it transparent. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The transparency works in the solid view but not in rendered mode. If it matters, I have some keyframes related to scale attached to that mesh text object.

I had followed one tutorial that led to me the above step. I have also seen this question [Alpha transparency not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52003/alpha-transparency-not-working) but it did not work for me.

**Question:**

> **Why is my method not working?**

Comment: It works in viewport because you adjusted alpha transparence only for viewport (Material > *Settings* > *Viewport Color* ); for rendering shader should be present

Comment: @MrZak Oh, it was a silly mistake! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render transparency in Cycles you need a transparency shader.

Setup your nodes in this kind of configuration, and set your key frames on the "Fac" value of the "Mix Shader" :

[image]