# Blender 2.8 transparency/alpha clip not working

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials, transparency

Doing exactly what was suggested in

[Making a realistic infinite mirror tunnel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48226/making-a-realistic-infinite-mirror-tunnel/48231#48231)

[Alpha transparency not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52003/alpha-transparency-not-working)

I ended up with:

a Material:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In Render:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: You are referring to transparency then to making infinite tunnel. Which is it? Could you clarify your question and problem please? Highlight what's "not working" in your screenshots may be?

Comment: @Bruno Transparency; I want to make the windows transparent (at the moment they have a blueish hue).

Comment: what does the "infinite mirror tunnel" have to do with this?

Comment: The answers make a reference to transparency: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48230/90593

Comment: The link you are referring to is a reflection bounce problem, not transparency. In your case, try to change Blend Mode from Alpha Clip to Alpha Blend in the material panel settings options

Comment: Instead of showing the reference image on the right , please show the results you are getting when you render. Edit your question to clarify what you want to do and what you are getting.

Comment: Fixed. Will answer later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Alpha controls transparency directly in the material:

[image]