# Cycles Render Material with black result [this is a bug; no problem with 2.77]

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I am viewing a 3D scene using the viewport. This problem also appears when using the *Render* button. I am having black results for my *Glass BSDF* stones. When I zoom out, I get black results. On the contrary, when I zoom in, I get good results. How can I achieve good results in every case? Blender 2.77a

[image: material rendering black]

[image: cycles material nodes]

[image: material rendering correctly]

I include a short version error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3322974/BlackStones.blend

Hardware: Mac Pro 5,1; Memory 24gb; 2 processors 2,26 ghz; AMD Radeon HD 7950 3072 MB; OSX El Capitan 10.11.5; Rendering using CPU

Comment: Can you upload a .blend file?

Comment: Try increasing the transparency bounces... possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48226/making-a-realistic-infinite-mirror-tunnel/48231#48231

Comment: You have a link to download. This is a short version.

Comment: Weird... this might actually be a bug. Edit your question and add your hardware info.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the file you uploaded, it renders fine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ra4pB.jpg

Comment: if you using smooth shading for that stones, try to add edge split modificator and play with split angle. smooth shading sometimes giving weird black shading.

Comment: It seems a bug, Matt.

Comment: Thank you Cegaton. Are you using same Blender Version and OS X ?

Comment: @jagoji3d No, I stay away from Macs and Radeons...

Comment: It's not exactly a bug. It's just an unsupported feature. Check out my new answer.

Comment: Welp... we've beat this one from just about every angle there is. I think it's safe to say definitively: It's a bug.

Comment: Does anybody know how to send a bug to Blender ?

Answer (score 1):

Your card is not fully supported by Blender.

From [the Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL):

> Radeon HD 7000 series (southern islands)   | Windows 7 x64 | Catalyst Beta 15.04   | Works (**Not all features**)

To confirm that this is the problem, disable GPU render and use CPU render, and the problem should go away. CPU will be MUCH slower, but it will support all features.

If the problem still exists with ONLY CPU rendering, then this is not the right answer.

Comment: The problems exits with only cpu rendering. Rendering with 2.77 (no 2.77a) is ok.

Comment: Wow, yup. That's a straight-up bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the Render Distance for your viewport. They might be black because they're being clipped by the far clipping plane.

Press <kbd>n</kbd> to open the settings for the viewport, and find the "distance" field. Increasing that might help.

If that works, you should also check the "Start" and "End" values on the Camera itself, because they are managed separately.

Comment: I suppose that clipping is for complete scene. I have increased my Viewport Clipping to: Start:1mm End 10 km with same results.

Answer (score 0):

This could also have happened, if you disabled "Camera" in the visibility settings of the gem object.

Look in the Object tab for the crystals, and make sure "Camera" is selected in the visibility section.

[image]

Comment: Camera is selected

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from the sphere "DomeEsfera" that is emitting light from a voronoi texture that is not visible to the camera but is the only light in your scene.
[image: voronoi object]
You have to zoom out to see it and activate "camera" in the visibility of your object tab to see it.
As it's the only light on glossy objects on 360°, you can easily see the black (no light). You have to add some other lights, or use a colorRamp to limit the black to mid-grey, or use a HDR image as background...

Comment: You have 3 more cameras without render problem. Try it.