# How to make infinite mirror room in eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, mirror, reflection

Alright I looked at [Making a realistic infinite mirror tunnel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48226/making-a-realistic-infinite-mirror-tunnel) and am trying to make an infinite mirror room in 2.8 eevee.

The answer says to increase light path bounces, but obviously this doesnt apply in eevee where lighting settings are limited to:

[image]

What Ive tried is making a mirror material (100% metallic, 0% rough) and put a reflection plane on every wall. I then upped the distance to like 5m on each -

[image]

however I still get maybe one reflection of the center object at best.
How can I do this in eevee?

Answer (score 1):

Looking for answer to this question I found this

https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/nb3niz/how_to_see_mirrors_in_mirrors_in_blender_eevee/

> I'd like mirror reflections to be visible in other mirrors in Eevee.
> Can I do this with the kind of mirror that relies on reflection planes
> and principled metallic materials with backface culling (in this case
> in the shader but could have been set in Material Settings instead)?
>
> Currently, mirrors appear in other mirrors as grey surfaces.

And in general the answer seems to be

> Eevee can't do this.

I do remember seeing a script that took the output of a camera in the scene and showed that on a surface - making it function as a mirror, and perhaps allowing it to do more than reflection planes. But I can't find it anymore :-/